# UITableViewCell Not Adjusting Properly?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell that contains a UILabel. At times this UILabel contains a lot of text, so it must contain multiple lines. I have the following code in ViewDidLoad:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140
```

In addition, I have set constraints for my UILabel within the Cell in main.storyboard.

When the amount of text covers one line or covers two lines, the label correctly shows all of the text. However, when the amount of text is three lines or greater, anything past the two-line mark gets cut off. How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: share pictures of what you expected and what you get instead please.

Comment: Did you constrain the label's top and bottom to the cell? Make vertical content hugging priority to 250 and vertical compression resistance to 1000

Comment: Yes, the label has leading and trailing constraints.

Comment: You need top and bottom constraints for your label to expand the cell's height.

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Comment: You need to make sure following things,
1) Your label's numberOfLines = 0
2) Your label have top and bottom constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You should add constraints to top, bottom, trailing and leading for your label and set `numberOfLines` to 0.